# What are some ways that I can develop C++ apps in Linux from a Windows workstation?

Tags: c++, windows, linux, ide, qt-creator

I'm developing C++ apps for Linux, but my workstation is Windows 7. I've read that Visual Studio is the strongest C++ IDE for Windows, but I actually want to execute the code on Ubuntu and be able to use a more graphically pleasing debugger than gdb, although the functionality of gdb is pretty good. I'm really happy with valgrind as well, but again, I'd like to be able to leverage that in an IDE in windows.

I currently use QtCreator as my C++ IDE and I edit the files over a samba mount to the linux box. I use Putty to run the Linux commands. I use git as my source control system, gcc as my compiler and cmake as my build system. I like QtCreator, but as I have it configured, I'm not taking advantage of code-completion or debugging.

The closest thing I've seen is CodeWarrior. It allows for executing code on remote embedded systems and a full debugger. Has anyone ever used this for general app development on Ubuntu?

Is QtCreator the right IDE for me? Is there something else that I can do to configure it so that it'll give me those rich IDE features that I'm looking for? Or should I look to another IDE? Also, are there some tools that I've neglected to mention that would make C++ development easier on a Linux box from a Windows workstation?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Will your programs be portable to Windows also?

Comment: No. They're are only intended to be run on linux. Specifically, I'm writing modules for nginx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear, you run QtCreator on windows?
If so, you can run QtCreator in Linux,
plus install nxserver on Linux,
and nxclient on windows (http://www.nomachine.com/).

So you run nxclient on windows, login to linux,
and work on linux, in compare with virtual machines,
you get more prefomance.

Comment: Yup, I run QtCreator on Windows. I'm a web developer and most of what I do it look at browsers (which run way better in Windows). So Windows is my workstation of choice, but Linux is my server of choice (running c++ code). I hadn't thought of nomachine, I'll check it out. Thank you. +1 for useful contribution.

Comment: Also if you perfectionist, and think that server should not have gui on it (nxserver require gui on server), you can try install xserver from cygwin, and tunnel X11 traffic from server to you Windows machine through SSH, but this require more knowledge and efforts.

Comment: Plus you can try WinGDB, plugin for VS to debug code on linux, from Windows via ssh: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/54b953c9-fd8a-4d6f-8c98-d0a1a786cbbe

Comment: Awesome. Great suggestions user1034749! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use VirtualBox and linux virtual machines?

Comment: I prefer to have a separate Linux box for my development. But either way, that's not really the question that I'm asking.

Comment: Do you want to compile & link under Windows an ELF binary executable for Linux? Why?

Comment: No, I use gcc as my compiler on linux. I just want to leverage the rich user interface of Windows to write code for Linux servers.

Comment: I was thinking of a multiscreen setup with one OS on each, and mouse pointer integration? so you can seamlessly switch between them? And then do some SMB shares as you currently are or some virtual box folder shares?

Comment: That's a good solution James, it's just not the solution to the problem I'm having. That's just the solution of how to run Linux on Windows.

Comment: I thought that might be the case... Was hoping it might get you close enough to your goal... THB I'm completely stuck on how to achieve this without @user1034749 x11 tunnelling (which is quite groovy)

Answer (score 1):

X Windows.

You could install Cygwin to run an X11 server on your Windows 7 desktop, then run an X11 graphical IDE like QtCreator on your Linux server that renders directly to your Cygwin Windows 7 desktop. I actually tried setting this up with Code::Blocks on openSUSE and Cygwin on Windows 7 just a few weeks ago because I'm in the same situation you're in. It works... kind of. There are weird intermittent errors.

Your scenario is exactly the scenario that the X Windows system was designed for, and it is awesome in concept, but the actual X11 protocol design and implementation is, I gather, old and pretty hairy. I have very little experience with X, but the people who do have lots of experience with it seem to complain about it a lot, and I suppose there are good reasons for that. Too bad, because it would be wonderful if there were a technology like X Windows that worked. AJAX is basically a cheap hack for solving the same kind of problem that X Windows tried to solve... running a remote application with local rendering of a rich GUI.

I gave up on X and I still do the same thing you do: I have putty and Samba-mounted files that I edit with Visual Studio. Visual Studio is the best text editor I've ever used. All the other Visual Studio IDE features are gravy.

Comment: Thanks James. +1 for very useful contributions.

Answer (score 0):

There's some solutions :

- VmWare : not free but really good
- Virtualbox : free but less powerfull than VmWare
- KVM/Qemu : Free but less powerfull than VmWare

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that's also not the question that I'm asking. I'm not trying to run Linux on Windows.